# Deploying a Golang (Beego) in production

Tags: nginx, go, beego

I came from a PHP background w/c is you can easily throw a PHP file in a server and that's it! How about in Golang, to be specific is the Beego framework because I already created a website using Beego but my stopper is (Q1)How to deploy in Ubunto and NGINX environment? (Q2)Do i need to compile the Beego project before deploying? (Q3)Do i need NGINX/Apache as server or use the built-in "run" of Beego?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

How to deploy in Ubuntu and NGINX environment?

1. Install Golang and run your Golang app on a particular port at localhost (say localhost:9000).
2. Install Nginx (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)
3. Choose a domain or subdomain that you wish to point to your Golang App.
4. Create Nginx server block (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)

   Example Server block pointing to Golang App running at localhost:9000:

   ```
   server {
           listen 80;
           server_name my.domain.com;

           location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For         
           $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_pass_request_headers on;
           proxy_read_timeout 150;
       }
   }
   ```
5. To run your program efficiently, you may use supervisor (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)

Answer (score 0):

1 - Pretty much install golang (Using the built-in version: `sudo apt-get install golang-go` or [Detailed guide](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu)) and build the project or simply copy the built project and their libs if needed;

2 - Ideally, the production environment shouldn't include the source codes on most scenarios, therefore a built server could be better.

3 - Although not required, most people recommend to run golang behind a nginx. The reason for that is due to several optimizations (eg:static files serving) made on NGinx/Apache, which you would be missing on direct running your bin on server 80.

Side notes:
- the `go run ...` is the same thing as the `go build ...` + run the built executable
- If you are just deploying the binary, build using the same OS / configurations.
- Remember to follow the basic security guides, just open the ports needed, secure the server before deploying, limit users access, etc.